# Alice's connection with her clones in the simulations

Tags: resident-evil

In [Resident Evil: Retribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil%3a_Retribution), there is a scene where Alice wakes up to find that she is a housewife with a husband and daughter, a daughter who happens to be deaf and uses sign language to communicate

The scene progresses innocently enough but soon degenerates into mayhem as they are attacked by intruders who, infected by a [virus](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Virus) that transforms them into zombie like creatures, are hell-bent on biting uninfected victims. Following a series of daringly heroic acts, Alice escapes the house with her daughter and seeks refuge in the cupboard of an upstairs bedroom in a home not far away. One of the zombies finds them, and, after a brief struggle Alice throws him over the banisters, killing him.

At this point, as if the whole thing is a dream, Alice finds herself in a non specific bedroom, she turns to face her husband, his face is covered in blood and slightly chewed up, he opens his mouth to attack... Alice wakes up again in an umbrella holding cell...

Was that a dream? Was she really there? Was that the experience of a clone, and is Alice somehow in connection with her clones? Able to experience things through them and share their memories?

Later in the movie as Alice makes her escape from the facility, she comes across the house where the earlier scene had occured, once inside she finds the "daughter", who instantly recognises her as her mother, then suddenly Alice is talking in sign language and she remembers who this girl is.

How come? How did she learn sign language? Did she have a real daughter before all of this madness started, a daughter who was deaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly [Resident Evil: Extinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil_%28film_series%29) starts with what looks like a flashback sequence of Alice attempting to escape from an Umbrella facility. however there is a twist and it is revealed that this is an Alice clone.

So the sequence in Resident Evil: Retribution is almost certainly a play on the previous theme. For in-universe terms this will be either clone memory that original Alice has incorporated through her psychic abilities or, less likely, a vision, again gained through her psychic abilities.

From the Wikipedia page:

> reveals that the base is underwater and serves as a testing ground for
> experiments
>
> Along the way, Alice finds a clone of a young girl named Becky, who
> believes Alice is her mother

Comment: I saw resident evil: retribution before I saw resitdent evil: extinction. so, after watching resident evil:extinction recently I am convinced that alice shares a connection with her clones

Answer (score 0):

She doesn't know sign language; she just uses some gestures that she believes will be universally understood for simple phrases along the lines of "Are you okay" and "Stay here". And she always faces Becky when speaking, so Becky can at least primitively read her lips to clarify the hand gestures (no actual mention of lip reading in the dialogue though).

Answer (score 0):

She most certainly uses sign language. Mainly in the Russian Tunnel. Then later. Not simple gestures but actual sign language.